# What is the difference between iSpec2200 and S1000D specifications?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-maintenance

I know the iSpec2200 and S1000D are the specifications which are used in the aircraft maintenance manual, I have to know how they actually work in the aviation domain and what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

I've only worked with S1000D, but what I understand is that they share a common origin in ATA Spec100, with some differences being:

**iSpec2200**

- maintains a focus on "legacy", monolithic publications
- scope is more limited to aircraft
- specification costs money (https://publications.airlines.org/CommerceProductDetail.aspx?Product=274)

**S1000D**

- focuses on modular data, with concepts such as data modules and the CSDB
- scope is more generalized to any product (air, land, sea, etc.)
- specification is free (http://public.s1000d.org/Downloads/Pages/S1000DDownloads.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Answer (score 0):

S1000D is the successor of iSpec 2200 since 2012. The standard is now free of charge and can be easily downloaded from S1000D website.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but I _am_ surprised that an organization went from `iSpec<something>` to just `<something>` in its naming convention. I mean, dropping the "lowercase 'i', uppercase word" thing in the internet age? Whoda thunk it?? (Unless, of course, Apple sued...) Also, it's odd that they went from the numeric `2200` "backwards" to `1000`.  Everything about those two identifiers indicates (to me, at least) that `iSpec2200` is newer than `S1000D`.

Answer (score 0):

iSpec2200 is ATA 2100 + ATA 100 combined and was a means to make these standards more modern with a new improved numbering system and things like gender-neutral terms.  The ATA 100 is from 1956, and I'm not sure about the genesis of the ATA 2100.  Both were retired in 1999.

The S1000D is based on the iSpec2200 so as to enable a simple back-and-forth transition between the two of them.  The main difference in that the S1000D is embracing a digital future for output to web, mobile, pdf, ...  It is based on the authoring of data modules that are small topic-specific modules that are "specification agnostic" and allows the data to be converted to ATA 2100 if that is required by the customer (such as they have a publishing system that takes ATA documents as input) or to any output format imaginable.

And of course the data modules are combined to form a larger publication.